# Is a repeated measures design a crossed design?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, nested-models

I have read about the distinction between crossed and nested designs. I would like to know if a repeated measures design is a crossed or a nested one. I'm leaning towards crossed but I can't find any documentation to confirm.

Comment: These concepts are not related.

Comment: It could be either or neither.